# C++ MPI: std::merge on arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, merge, mpi, array-merge

I have an interesting problem here. I have some subarrays already sorted and I need to merge them into a big array sorted. I've try to do this in the code below but I don't get the result I'm expecting.

Could one of you guys told me what I'm doing wrong? Because I have no clue, my logic it's looks good I think..

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define N 32
#define ROOT 0

int A[N];  // this should be global

void quickSort(int*, int, int);
int partition(int*, int, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size;
    int rank;

    vector<int> result(N);

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int count = N / size;

    int *localArray = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    if (rank == ROOT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
        // master local copy
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            localArray[i] = A[i];

        for (int dest = 1; dest < size; ++dest) {
            MPI_Send(&A[dest * count], count, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("P0 sent a %d elements to P%d.\n", count, dest);
        }

        int source = 1;

        int sizeResult = count * 2;
        int sizeResult2 = count;

        int tmpVec[sizeResult2];
        int tm[sizeResult];

        MPI_Recv(tmpVec, count, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        for (int source = 2; source < size; source++) {
            MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            //-------------------------------HERE IS THE PROBLEM---------------------------
            merge(tmpVec, tmpVec + sizeResult2, localArray, localArray + count, tm);

            sizeResult2 = sizeResult;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeResult; i++) {
                tmpVec[i] = tm[i];
                cout << tm[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            sizeResult += count;
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeResult2; i++)
            cout << tmpVec[i] << " ";
        cout << endl << sizeResult2 << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            cout << A[i] << " ";

    }
    else {
        MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        quickSort(localArray, 0, count);

        MPI_Send(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
void quickSort(int* A, int p, int q) {
    int r;
    if (p < q) {
        r = partition(A, p, q);
        quickSort(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, r + 1, q);
    }
}

int partition(int* A, int p, int q) {
    int x = A[p];
    int i = p;
    int j;

    for (j = p + 1; j < q; j++) {
        if (A[j] <= x) {
            i = i + 1;
            swap(A[i], A[j]);
        }

    }
    swap(A[i], A[p]);
    return i;
}
```

How you can see, I'm try to merge first subarray with the second one, after I will merge the result of them with the third one and so on...

Comment: In this case it is fairly obvious what's wrong, but please be more careful in describing how the actual results differ from the expected results. "*I don't get the result I'm expecting.*" is usually not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory in your intermediate buffers (`tmpVec` and `tm`). To avoid that, simply make use of `std::vector` instead of bothering with low level arrays:

```
std::vector<int> tmpVec(count);
std::vector<int> tm;

MPI_Recv(tmpVec.data(), count, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

for (int source = 2; source < size; source++) {
    MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    merge(tmpVec.begin(), tmpVec.end(), localArray, localArray + count, std::back_inserter(tm));

    tmpVec = tm;
    tm.resize(0);
}
```

As a general hint, please consider the choice of your variable names more carefully. It is much easier to reason about code when the variable names are descriptive.

Going back to your actual problem, again: Use scatter & gather! It is fairly straight forward to use `std::inplace_merge` on a gathered contiguous array using a recursive mergesort. The trick is to use the offsets of each local portion that is already sorted, and add a "end" offset to that array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <algorithm>

#define N 16 
int A[N]; 

// This is basically textbook recursive merge sort using std::merge_inplace
// but it considers the offsets of segments that are already sorted
void merge_indexed(int data[], const int offsets[], size_t index_begin, size_t index_end)
{
    if (index_end - index_begin > 1) {
        auto index_middle = index_begin + (index_end - index_begin) / 2;
        merge_indexed(data, offsets, index_begin, index_middle);
        merge_indexed(data, offsets, index_middle, index_end);
        std::inplace_merge(&data[offsets[index_begin]], &data[offsets[index_middle]], &data[offsets[index_end]]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size;
    int rank;
    const int ROOT = 0; 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    auto remainder = N % size;
    int local_counts[size], offsets[size + 1];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        local_counts[i] = N / size;
        if (remainder > 0) {
            local_counts[i] += 1;
            remainder--;
        }
        offsets[i] = sum;
        sum += local_counts[i];
    }
    offsets[size] = sum;

    int localArray[local_counts[rank]];

    if (rank == ROOT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    MPI_Scatterv(A, local_counts, offsets, MPI_INT, localArray, local_counts[rank], MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    std::sort(&localArray[0], &localArray[local_counts[rank]]);

    MPI_Gatherv(localArray, local_counts[rank], MPI_INT, A, local_counts, offsets, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == ROOT) {
        //---------------Merge sections in localArray-------------------
        merge_indexed(A, offsets, 0, size);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```